Generate SBOM using CycloneDX for repository containing multiple languages
As a part of CI I want to generate SBOM and upload it to Dependency track. I would love to have one approach for all repositories I want to track. They can contain multiple technologies - nodejs, python, Go, etc. Even one repository can contain more dependency lock files.
In case of NodeJS project I have package.json with yarn.lock. The repository also contains generated documentation with some JS files. And contains some helper scripts.
Because of this I tried to use cdxgen which support everything and can find even js files and parse their content to guess the library. This works nice to scan all dependencies everywhere. The issue is that it doesn't recognize direct vs transitive dependencies.
Then I tried to use plugin for Vite on the main project. It did not found all dependencies and was not able to recognize anything about direct dependencies.
Best results were with cyclonedx-node-yarn which generated correctly transitive vs direct dependencies, it also looks like the list of components is correct. It was just much slower then rest of the options there.
The issue with cyclonedx-node-yarn I have is that I'll have to run different packages for different technologies and them merge them into one SBOM. Am I missing here something? Isn't there a way to generate all dependencies for any technology more easily and automatically into one file per folder and it's subfolder? Would it mean to write own script per project to generate these?

Consider looking at Syft, an open-source SBOM generator that can scan project folders containing software from diverse ecosystems. It can output the SBOM in CycloneDX format.
Installation of Syft
Syft is written in Go and is available as a pre-built single binary. There are packages for Windows, Mac, Linux. There's an easy installer shell script:
$ curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anchore/syft/main/install.sh | sh -s -- -b /usr/local/bin

Generate Text SBOM
This will analyze the directory (or container) and produce a human-readable SBOM as a text table. Note this is not the entire output, as it's pretty long. The steps to reproduce all this are at the bottom of my answer.
$ syft dir:./sbom-demo | (head; tail)
 ✔ Indexed file system sbom-demo
 ✔ Cataloged contents 5ce0d9d1e0410a9ea2edcd96c9fbf223f346c2e57ab044e60e706ba9d3d46eb0
   ├── ✔ Packages                        [112 packages]
   ├── ✔ File digests                    [32 files]
   ├── ✔ File metadata                   [32 locations]
   └── ✔ Executables                     [3 executables]
[0000]  WARN no explicit name and version provided for directory source, deriving artifact ID from the given path (which is not ideal)
NAME                          VERSION            TYPE
accepts                       1.3.8              npm
array-flatten                 1.1.1              npm
blinker                       1.9.0              python
body-parser                   1.20.3             npm
bytes                         3.1.2              npm
call-bind-apply-helpers       1.0.1              npm
call-bound                    1.0.3              npm
certifi                       2024.12.14         python
charset-normalizer            3.4.0              python

Generate CycloneDX SBOM
Syft supports numerous output formats, including cyclonedx-json and cyclonedx-xml.
$ syft dir:./sbom-demo -o cyclonedx-json > sbom.json
 ✔ Indexed file system ./sbom-demo
 ✔ Cataloged contents cdb4ee2aea69cc6a83331bbe96dc2caa9a299d21329efb0336fc02a82e1839a8
   ├── ✔ Packages                        [112 packages]
   ├── ✔ File digests                    [32 files]
   ├── ✔ File metadata                   [32 locations]
   └── ✔ Executables                     [3 executables]
[0000]  WARN no explicit name and version provided for directory source, deriving artifact ID from the given path (which is not ideal)

Validate CycloneDX SBOM
Here, we'll use the official sbom-utility validator to make sure the SBOM is spec-compliant.
$ sbom-utility validate -i sbom.json
Welcome to the sbom-utility! Version 'v0.17.1-pre' (sbom-utility) (linux/amd64)
===============================================================================
[INFO] Loading (embedded) default schema config file: 'config.json'...
[INFO] Loading (embedded) default license policy file: 'license.json'...
[INFO] Attempting to load and unmarshal data from: 'sbom.json'...
[INFO] Successfully unmarshalled data from: 'sbom.json'
[INFO] Determining file's BOM format and version...
[INFO] Determined BOM format, version (variant): 'CycloneDX', '1.6' (latest)
[INFO] Matching BOM schema (for validation): schema/cyclonedx/1.6/bom-1.6.schema.json
[INFO] Loading schema 'schema/cyclonedx/1.6/bom-1.6.schema.json'...
[INFO] Found schema dependencies: [jsf-0.82.schema.json spdx.schema.json]
[INFO] Added schema 'schema/cyclonedx/common/jsf-0.82.schema.json' to loader:...
[INFO] Added schema 'schema/cyclonedx/common/spdx.schema.json' to loader:...
[INFO] Compiling schema: 'schema/cyclonedx/1.6/bom-1.6.schema.json'...
[INFO] Schema 'schema/cyclonedx/1.6/bom-1.6.schema.json' loaded
[INFO] Validating 'sbom.json'...
[INFO] BOM valid against JSON schema: 'true'

Looks good
Examine the contents of the SBOM
Here, we get the numbers to show it's doing the right thing by finding packages from the go, node, and python ecosystems.
$ for p in golang npm pypi; do \
  echo -n $p; \
  jq . < sbom.json \
  | grep "purl\": \"pkg:$p" \
  | sort | uniq | wc -l ; done
golang      28
npm      70
pypi      12

I hope that helps.
Demo setup
Below is just what I did to set up the demo above. I'm just putting it here for completeness and reproducibility.
# Create main directory
mkdir sbom-demo
cd sbom-demo

# Set up Node.js project
mkdir nodejs-app
cd nodejs-app
cat > package.json << 'EOL'
{
  "name": "nodejs-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
EOL
npm install
cd ..

# Set up Python project
mkdir python-app
cd python-app
cat > requirements.txt << 'EOL'
requests==2.31.0
Flask==3.0.0
EOL
uv venv
source .venv/bin/activate
uv pip install -r requirements.txt
deactivate
cd ..

# Set up Go project
mkdir go-app
cd go-app
go mod init example.com/go-app
cat > main.go << 'EOL'
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    logger := logrus.New()
    logger.Info("Starting application")
}
EOL
go mod tidy
cd ..

